# Datagram client server on android in LAN

Tags: android, multithreading, android-intent, udp, datagram

I have client and server app running on separate android device but client cant communicate with server after alot of head bang i cant find out the error,Please check for the errors,
Thanks in advance
My client class is :

```
      public class MainActivity extends Activity {
     EditText et1;
     Button bt1;
      InetAddress IPAddress; 
   DatagramPacket  dp;
    String message;
  int SERVERPORT = 11111;
      String SERVER_IP = "192.168.1.101";
         DatagramSocket clientSocket;
      byte[] sendData;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    et1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
    bt1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.myButton);
    message=et1.getText().toString();







    bt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub







                new Thread(new ClientThread()).start();


        }
    });


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}





class ClientThread implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
         try {


                clientSocket = new DatagramSocket(SERVERPORT);


            } catch (SocketException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }




         try {


             IPAddress = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);


         } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } 
         sendData =  message.getBytes();     

         dp = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, IPAddress, SERVERPORT);




         try {


             clientSocket.send(dp);


         } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

         clientSocket.close();
         return;

        } 

    }



    }
```

My server is:

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {
TextView tv1,tv2;
InetAddress broadcastIP;
private Boolean shouldRestartSocketListen=true;
static String UDP_BROADCAST = "UDPBroadcast";
DatagramSocket serverSocket=null;
byte[] data=null;
DatagramPacket dp=null;
    int SERVERPORT = 11111;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tv1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    new Thread(new serverThread()).start();
}

class serverThread implements Runnable {
    private void listenAndWaitAndThrowIntent(InetAddress broadcastIP, Integer port) throws Exception {
        byte[] recvBuf = new byte[15000];

        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(recvBuf, recvBuf.length);

        while (shouldRestartSocketListen) {
            if (serverSocket == null || serverSocket.isClosed())
            {
                serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(port,broadcastIP);
            //  serverSocket.setBroadcast(true);
            }
        serverSocket.receive(packet);

        String senderIP = packet.getAddress().getHostAddress();
        String message = new String(packet.getData());
                    //Log.e("UDP", "Got UDB broadcast from " + senderIP + ", message: " +    message);
         tv1.setText(message);

        //broadcastIntent(senderIP, message);
        serverSocket.close();
        }
        }
    private void broadcastIntent(String senderIP, String message) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.UDP_BROADCAST);
        intent.putExtra("sender", senderIP);
        intent.putExtra("message", message);
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        try {
            broadcastIP = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.100");
        } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

            try {
                listenAndWaitAndThrowIntent(broadcastIP, SERVERPORT);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }

}

void stopListen() {
    shouldRestartSocketListen = false;
    serverSocket.close();

         }
         }
```

No log cat because i am running on real devices.

Comment: Logcat exists on real devices.

Comment: how can i get that? @mah

Comment: attach your USB and "adb logcat", same as for the emulator. You may need the USB driver from your device manufacturer, and you may need to enable development mode on the device settings.

Answer (score 0):

I can not add coments because of reputation but use asynctasks.. create one class for send and another for receive. I have put the two of then together... not tested.

```
public class SenderBroadcastAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, String> {

 Context context;
 public SenderBroadcastAsyncTask(Context context) {
     this.context = context.getApplicationContext();
 }
 @Override
 protected String doInBackground(File... imagen) {  

int port =1515;
    DatagramSocket socket = null;
    try {
        socket = new DatagramSocket(port);
    } catch (SocketException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        socket.setBroadcast(true);
    } catch (SocketException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    //////send socket
    int eport = 1616;
    InetAddress eip = null;
    try {
        eip = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.1");  ////SERVER IP ADDRESS ---- 
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    DatagramSocket esocket = null;
    try {
        esocket = new DatagramSocket(eport);
    } catch (SocketException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

/////sending 
string send = "something";
byte[] sendbyte = send.getBytes
DatagramPacket somedatagrampacket = new Datagrampacket(sendbyte,sendbyte.length,eip,eport);
esocket.send(somedatagrampacket)






//////Start receive
    while(true)
    {


        byte[] message = new byte[60*1024];
        DatagramPacket recv_packet = new DatagramPacket(message, message.length);


        try {
            socket.receive(recv_packet);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    ///Do something whit recv_packet
}



protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

///something to do whit results

   }
   }
```